# Laravel retrieve images from database

Tags: php, laravel-5

I need to display the stored images in my view.I've used the below code to store image in db,

```
     $file = Input::file('pic');
     $img = Image::make($file);
     Response::make($img->encode('jpeg'));
     $picture = new Car;
    $picture->cartype = Input::get('cartype');
    $picture->price = Input::get('price');

    $FileName            = Input::file('pic')->getClientOriginalName();
    $FilePath = public_path('') .'/images/'. $FileName;
    $picture->name = $FilePath;
    $picture->save();
```

In my controller( to retrieve image)

```
public function index()
{

            $cars = DB::table('car_category')->get();
           return view('category.category',['cars'=>$cars]);


}
```

How should I retrieve and display the images in view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are storing the image name in the database and uploading it in a directory then you can easily display it by simply fetching the name from database, returning the name to view and append the name to a hard-coded directory address like this -

```
<img src="/images/{{ $imageVariableName }}">
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks.I've already tried it.`@foreach( $cars as $car ) 
   
            
       <tr class="active"> 
   
            <td>{{$car->id}}</td>
            <td>{{$car->cartype}}</td>
            <td>{{$car->price}}</td>
            <td>{{$car->seats}}</td>
            
            <td><img src="{{ $car->name }}"></td>`

Comment: It return emplty row

Comment: Is the issue with my storage path?I'm storing in db as **C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\movecab\public/images/1509446707.jpg**

Comment: Just store `1509446707.jpg` in the database and retrieve it on view using - 
<img src="/images/{{ $car->name }}

Comment: I 've tried it I get the error in my console as "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: It works Thanks with the code  ``td><img src="images/{{ $car->name }}"></td>`

Comment: Great. Good luck :)

Comment: How do I resize image in laravel blade